# Why guage.js guages doesn't render on my web page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using [guage.js](https://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/) to make this graph from this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdvillanueva/kv2q76Lf/112/). When I added the same code to my web page, it doesn't render as shown here:

[image]

Upon inspecting on Chrome dev tools, the element still exist but with no height and width:

[image]

What's odd is that I have defined the width and height on the parent div and the canvas itself but but it forcefully changes it back with its own CSS properties with no width and height. There are no related errors on the Chrome dev tools console either, that means guage.js is working but not rendering. Please see my code below:

```
<div style="margin: auto; width: 200px; height: 160px;">
    <canvas id="foo" width="200" height="160"></canvas>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var opts = {
        angle: -0.10, /// The span of the gauge arc
        lineWidth: 0.2, // The line thickness
        pointer: {
            length: 0.9, // Relative to gauge radius
            strokeWidth: 0.035 // The thickness
        },
        colorStart: '#6FADCF', // Colors
        colorStop: '#8FC0DA', // just experiment with them
        strokeColor: '#E0E0E0', // to see which ones work best for you
        staticZones: [{
            strokeStyle: "#F03E3E",
            min: -3,
            max: -2.5
        }, // Red from 100 to 130
        {
            strokeStyle: "#FFDD00",
            min: -2.5,
            max: -2
        }, // Yellow
        {
            strokeStyle: "#30B32D",
            min: -2,
            max: 2
        }, // Green
        {
            strokeStyle: "#FFDD00",
            min: 2,
            max: 2.5
        }, // Yellow
        {
            strokeStyle: "#F03E3E",
            min: 2.5,
            max: 3
        } // Red
        ],
        staticLabels: {
            font: "10px sans-serif", // Specifies font
            labels: [2, 2.5, 3, 0, -2, -2.5, -3], // Print labels at these values
            color: "#000000", // Optional: Label text color
            fractionDigits: 1 // Optional: Numerical precision. 0=round off.
        }
    };
    var target = document.getElementById('foo'); // your canvas element
    var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts); // create sexy gauge!
    gauge.maxValue = 3; // set max gauge value
    gauge.setMinValue(-3); // set min value
    gauge.set(1.22); // set actual value
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have to put something in canvas then you can see.

see you just try to to apply color in your div tag and check its consumes any space or not

Comment: The div has ```style="margin: auto; width: 200px; height: 160px;"``` and my canvas has ```width="200" height="160"```. If I remove the code for initializing the guage, it does consume space because it follows the CSS I defined. But when guage.js initialized the height and width is 0. I tried manually editing the CSS and the height and width of the canvas element with Chrome dev tools but it's still not rendering.